# A problem related to polynomial rings and ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k[X]$ be a polynomial ring and let $I,J$ be ideal of $k[X]$. In the ring $k[X,t]$ ($t$ is a new indeterminate) is considered the ideal $L=tI+(1-t)J$. Prove that $I\cap J=L \cap k[X]$.

I would be really grateful if you could help me to prove it.

Comment: Please see the [FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/29335) on how to ask questions, especially the part about "avoid no-clue questions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let do this:

$$ti+(1-t)j \in L \cap k[X] \Longrightarrow t(i-j)+j \in k[X] \Longrightarrow (i-j)=0 \Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow t(i-j)+j=j=i \in (I \cap J)$$

For inverse:

$$l \in I \cap J \Longrightarrow l = lt+(1-t)l \in k[X]$$

So they are equal.